# Aspnet Identity Security Stamp Validation always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to use Aspnet Identity in a single page web application that communicates with server using web api. I am trying to configure Security Stamp Validation to log out users if they sign in from different machine. My configuration is as follows-

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

.....

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});

services.AddAuthentication().Services
.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".appdomain";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context => {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context => {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});

...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true
        });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

And my login method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<JsonRecord> Login([FromBody] Login login)
{
    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(login.Username);
    if (user != null)
    {
        var success = _directoryService.ValidateUser(login.Username, login.Password);
        if (success)
        {
            await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            return WrapJsonRecord(true, null, user);
        }
    }
    return WrapJsonRecord(false, "Username/password invalid");
}
```

However, any request after 10 seconds gets a 401 return, even when the user did not log in from anywhere else.

I am using custom UserStore and database and targeting .NET framework 4.6.2

If anyone can tell what I am doing wrong that would be great help.

Comment: Maybe hook into [OnRefreshingPrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.securitystampvalidatoroptions.onrefreshingprincipal) and/or [OnValidatePrincipal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookieauthenticationevents.onvalidateprincipal) to get some additional insight.  Also did you implement [IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Core/IUserSecurityStampStore.cs)?

Comment: You probably need to flush their auth info on the server with SignOut / AuthenticationCookie